# Reconstruct a found.000 corrupted harddrive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, chkdsk, file-corruption

On Windows 10.  I have a spinning disk hard drive which was corrupted by a bad external docking unit and has a left me a found.000 folder, inside are about 250 folders called dir0001.chk - dir0250.chk.
Inside each of these folders are the files I want (seemingly in good condition, with the correct file type associations), just spread out all over the place.  Is there any way I can reconstruct the original folder format of all these files?
Thanks for the advice

Comment: Slowly, by hand, one at a time..  The names are gone, that is why you are looking at what you are looking at.  Some if not all of those files are partial..

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Your comment should probably have been posted as an answer so I've posted it as a Community Wiki. Answers don't have to be long, particluarly when the answer to the quetion is "No".

Comment: Thats OK @AnthonyGeoghegan .. but I get your point.  I am not here for points. :)  Next time, I will post as an answer.  If I did this more, I would surely have more points but more important is that the answer would be searchable.  Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Had you posted your comment as an answer, I would have upvoted it. I'm guessing the 4 people who upvoted your comment would also have upvoted it as an answer and maybe user15635022 might have accepted it (so that others would know this question was answered). Oh, and the beauty of community wiki is that nobody gets points and anyone can edit. :) Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Slowly, by hand, one at a time. The names are gone; that is why you are looking at what you are looking at. Some, if not all, of those files are partial.